# Is it possible to force a range of date within a SELECT cause with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, select

I need your help with Oracle.
I need to do a control report by using a table called `restaurant_info` The table looks like this :

```
|------------------|---------------|
|     COMP_NAME    |      CODE     |
|------------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |
|------------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |
|------------------|---------------|
```

I have another table which is called `restaurant_inc` returns the income of the restaurants at the end of a day.

```
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        CODE      |   DATE_RES    |      INCOME     |
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        PIC       |   14/04/2020  |      15908      |   
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        PIC       |   15/04/2020  |      10890      |
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        PIC       |   16/04/2020  |      10000      |
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        PIC       |   17/04/2020  |      12890      |
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        PIC       |   18/04/2020  |      13890      |
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        PIC       |   20/04/2020  |      10880      |
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        PIC       |   21/04/2020  |      9890       |
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|        PIC       |   22/04/2020  |       9500      |
|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
```

As you can see the table displays the income of a restaurant identified by a code. What I want to do is to do a query from that reads `COMP_NAME`,`CODE` and that tells whether the income is missing or not by using a CASE statement. The result looks like this :

```
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     COMP_NAME    |      CODE     |   DATE_RES    |      CHECK    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   14/04/2020  |               |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   15/04/2020  |               |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   16/04/2020  |               |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   17/04/2020  |               |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   18/04/2020  |               |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   19/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   20/04/2020  |               |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   21/04/2020  |               |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|     Pizza Co     |      PIC      |   22/04/2020  |               |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |   14/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |   15/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |   16/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |   17/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |   18/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |   20/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |   21/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    So Asian      |      SOA      |   22/04/2020  |    Missing    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
```

As you can see in my exemple the value of `CHECK` for `So Asia` is empty because there is no row in the table `restaurant_inc` that displays the income.
I don't know how to add the date in my select query and how to handle the missing values in the table `restaurant_inc`. In my control request I need to tell the range of date for the column `DATE_RES`.Could you help me to find a way to make this control request?

EDIT : I tried this query :

```
SELECT inf.comp_name,inf.code,inc.date_res,case when 
(select income from restaurant_inc r where r.date_res=inc.date_res)
is null then 'Missing' end as CHECK FROM restaurant_info inf,
restaurant_inc inc where inf.code=inc.code and
inc.date_res>=to_date('14/04/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') 
and inc.date_res<=to_date('22/04/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

My range of dates is between the 14th of April and the 22nd of April.
It doesn't display 'Missing' for `So Asia` and `Pizza Co`. I think this is because the date is not in the table `restaurant_inc`.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date range that you want to search over isn't actually in any of your tables. So the way I usually see this done is to create a new table to hold the dates that you want to search over, and cartesian/cross join it to your base table.

```
-- set up sample data
with restaurant_info as (select 'Pizza Co' as comp_name, 'PIC' as code from dual union select 'So Asian', 'SO' from dual),
    restaurant_inc as (select 'PIC' as code,to_date('14/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_res,15908 as income from dual union
                        select 'PIC',to_date('15/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),10890 from dual union
                        select 'PIC',to_date('16/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),10000 from dual union
                        select 'PIC',to_date('17/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),12890 from dual union
                        select 'PIC',to_date('18/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),13890 from dual union
                        select 'PIC',to_date('20/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),10880 from dual union
                        select 'PIC',to_date('21/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),9890  from dual union
                        select 'PIC',to_date('22/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), 9500 from dual)
-- actual query
select r.comp_name, r.code, d.date_res, case when i.date_res is null then 'Missing' end as "Check"
from restaurant_info r
cross join (select date '2020-04-14' + level as date_res from dual 
    connect by level <= 8) d 
left join restaurant_inc i on r.code = i.code and i.date_res = d.date_res
order by 1, 3;
```

In this case, I'm creating an inline view (aliased `d`) which holds the days from 04-14 to 04-22. Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your solution looks nice but I have a question : why "does select date '2020-04-14'" works? Why didn't you need to convert it into a date?

Comment: this is because Oracle performs implicit conversion if the data types are different. the rules could be seen here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF30027 so there is an implicit to_date during the execution, however providing explicitly to_date with the proper format mask is not only possible but is advised

Comment: @micklesh is incorrect, it is not an implicit conversion. `date '2020-04-14'` is an [Oracle date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062), so you don't need a format mask to convert it from a string to a date.